Can my boss share Cloud account contacts with me?
I am an Executive Assistant, and I wish to add new contacts to my bosses iCloud account. How does he add me to his contacts as an editor/creator? Is it possible?

Apple does not support delegates for iCloud.
Your boss would have to log in to your device with his credentials or hand over control of those credentials to you.
You could create a second iCloud account and both of you use that in addition to the primary account, but for work purposes, I recommend professional level contact services.
Get a Fastmail account and you can manage that easily from your device (Apple or Windows or Android) and manage his work calendar and contacts and they will sync natively on iOS and macOS. This is similar to adding a second iCloud account, but has many more features than iCloud and professional paid support.

https://www.fastmail.help/hc/en-us/articles/360060590913-Sharing-contacts-on-other-devices

He can still have personal contacts in iCloud and work contacts and they all show up in all the places needed.
I’ve used Fastmail for years and its spam handling is exceptional and learns your needs better than iCloud spam email control.  It handles custom domains better than iCloud does, in my experience.
Also check out Flexibits. Their cardhop app, calendar scheduling, and conference call detection are next-level fantastic. If you need any one of those unique features, get that too or instead of Fastmail.

https://flexibits.com/cardhop

Both offer free trials and both are high value, low cost, professional level tools that are extremely reliable.

My wife is a secondary Apple iCloud account on my devices and I am a secondary on hers. Secondary accounts can sync any or all of Mail, Contacts, Calendar and reminders. We both see all each others Contacts with no special account.
